# Connecting to .net webservice from php - return buffer not ended

Tags: php, .net, web-services, sockets, fgets

I have a php based website which is connecting to a third party SOAP web service.

I am creating and parsing the request and response envelope xml successfully. The only issue is with the actual communication. I am using sockets, as I saw this code as an example and was able to modify it to work for our case.

```
$socket = fsockopen("ssl://***",443);
if ($socket!==false){
  $request =  "POST /***.asmx HTTP/1.1\n".
              "Host: ***\n".
              "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\n".
              "Content-Length: ".strlen($request)."\n".
              "SOAPAction: \"http://***\"\n\n".
              $request."\n";

  fputs($socket, $request);
```

However reading the response was always hanging until the connection timed out. This is due to the method I use to read `FGETS` requiring an end of line or end of file marker, which it doesn't receive from the web service. As a result I am forced to read the response one byte at a time and check if the SOAP envelope is closed, and then manually stop. This seems somewhat inefficient to me.

```
  while (!feof($socket) && substr($response,-16) != "</soap:Envelope>" ) {
     $response .= fgets($socket,2);  // force read one byte at a time
  }
```

So, my question(s) are:
Is this a known phenomenon for .net web services?
Is there a better way to perform this communication, or specifically the read (other than FGETS)?

And on a slightly unrelated note, why does the fgets function require me to specify 2, to read 1 byte? (Or is this related to the charset, ie: if the response is in utf8 then 1 character is represented by 2 bytes)